# Document designer interface design

Tags: java, user-interface, wysiwyg

Im working on coding a WYSIWYG document designer. The basic intent of this designer is to be capable of both reading(loading) and creating multiple documents written in a variety of templating languages (ZPL, XSL-FO etc).
Now for the sake of building a WYSIWYG designer, i plan to have an elegant UI which the user can play around with to create/edit the document. 
The compulsory needs of the UI is that --

1. The UI should be such that the user must be able to pick or
   choose elements and be able to drop them off on the UI. Once
   dropped, the position of the elements should be capable of allowing
   repositioning.
2. The UI must associate the spatial postioning of elements to the
   element's metadata (say, x coordinate,y coordinate, height ,width
   etc).
3. The UI must be capable of seamlessly passing on the elements and
   their spatial positions to a backend module,written in Java, that
   would wither edit or create the document in the specified templating
   language.

Im having trouble in deciding what to implement the UI in. I tried Swing and found it to be not great(was pretty rigid for my needs). Any suggestions with regard to what can be used to build the UI described above would be of immense help.

Answer (score 1):

Your underpinnings options are pretty much Swing or SWT.

Not sure what you mean by "rigid"; Swing is a pretty good GUI framework architecturally, although some prefer SWT. Not sure how JavaFX will end up, but it has some nice features.

[XUI](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/27383) layers on top. Or take the [Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/) approach, although I'm not sure it's a great fit for the type of application you're working on. Or use Groovy/JRuby/etc. to make many aspects of working with Swing/etc. less painful.

IIRC there are Java bindings for QT as well, if the QT licensing works for you.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great suggestions.
Im fascinated by JavaFx but @G_H's suggestion of RCP also makes sense. Im exploring both these options right now and then will pick one of the above as an answer. Boy i wish i could choose more that 1 response as an answer ! :)

Comment: @ping RCPs may be a better choice. You could also look at things like iReport, OpenOffice, and similar Java-based document/word processors/page layout design apps for ideas and starting points. RCPs won't deal with your primary domain, but they do deal with some housekeeping.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you'll be better served by some rich client platform (RCP) like Eclipse or NetBeans. Both are probably best known as IDEs, but the IDEs are actually built on top of the respective platforms. Using an RCP will take a lot of responsibility out of your hands. Existing plugins/modules can be made to interoperate with your code and facilities such as perspectives (Eclipse) or rearranging panels are accounted for.

Like Dave Newton hinted at, JavaFX could also be a candidate. JavaFX 2.0 is now out and no longer requires the scripting language used in 1.0, instead opting for a Java API that'll feel more natural to experienced Java developers. And it can be used within Swing.